# returncode in Python subprocess module always returns 0

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I am triggering a shell script using a Python script and get its exit code for further processing. I am using the `subprocess` module. But when I try to capture the return code for further processing it is always 0 even if the script failed.

Below is my Python code:

```py
import subprocess
import os
    
    
dpath = "/home/admin/temp"
password = "password"
password_bytes = bytes(password + '\n', encoding='utf-8')
proc = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', '-S', 'sh', os.path.join(dpath,'test1.sh'),'hello'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate(input=password_bytes)
    
print(proc.returncode)
print(out)
if proc.returncode == 0:
    print("success")
else:
    print("fail")
```

Below is my shell script

```sh
cat file.txt #File.txt does not exist
echo $?
```

Below is my python output

```
0
b'1\n'
success
```

You can see `print(out)` gives exit code 1 but `proc.returncode` gives 0.

Answer (score 1):

The return code is `0` because you have added an `echo` statement, which does not fail.
Try simply having `cat file` where `file` does not exist, without the echo statement.

Comment: To point out explicitly why that is, the exit code of a script is the exit code of the last command in the script; so, here, `echo`.